# In spring-boot, how to log MDC using application properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, mdc

In my [spring-boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) project I am using Logback-"Mapped Diagnostic Context" [MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) for logging diagnostic context.

MDC-data is not logged (to console or file) by default.

Is there a way for getting this MDC logs into the output-log, using only application properties?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

spring-boot provides some application properties for this. Have a look at [common-application-properties.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

You can find *logging.pattern.level* here. By setting

```
logging.pattern.level=%5p %mdc
```

data from MDC will be logged, too.

Comment: thats a very useful link